# prove that if $\gcd(r,m)=1=\gcd(r',m)$, then $\gcd(rr',m)=1$

Tags: number-theory

I know that $\gcd(r,m)$ and $\gcd(r',m)$ can be written as a linear combination. I can't figure out how to write $\gcd(rr',m)$ as a combination.

Attempt at proof:

Let $\gcd(r,m)=ar+bm$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(r',m)=cr'+dm$ for $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $\gcd(r,m)$ multiplied by $\gcd(r',m)$ so that equals $acrr'+(ard+bcr'+bdm)m=1$ and now we're done.

Is this correct?

Comment: By $(r,m)$ do you mean greatest common divisor?

Comment: @rtybase Yes, sorry about that, I'll fix it.

Comment: @rtybase I think I figured it out, could you check it?

Comment: Yes this is good, but it's not technically enough. You will probably have to assume that $\gcd(r\cdot r',m)=d>1$, then, from the relation you established, you will deduce that $d \mid 1$ and then you have a contradiction and the statement in the title proved.

Comment: "now we're done" deserves elaboration. You should *justify* why $\,j\, rr' + k\, m = 1\,\Rightarrow\, \gcd(rr',m) = 1.\ $ Also if you are using Bezout's gcd identity then you should *explicitly* say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say there exist a prime $p$ that divides $rr'$ and $m$. Then, by Euclid lemma $p|r$ or $p|r'$. But then $p|r$ and $p|m$ or  $p|r'$ and $p|m$. In each case we get a contradiction buy assumption. So $gcd(rr',m)=1$.

Comment: I'd say, add a reference to Euclid lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma and it will deserve a +1

Comment: @john nobody Could you check my attempt at proof?

Comment: @Fred: Yes it is OK!